# How to fix "Configuration Problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace context"?

Tags: spring

I was trying to run application in eclipse, it was running fine. I created jar using Maven install, and while running the jar I am getting the error "Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [appContext.xml]"

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="package"></context:component-scan>
                ...
```

[Snap of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgbHO.png)

Comment: Can you post the structure of your project? The appContext.xml is inside your resources folder?

Comment: @Flip123go, Yes. It is placed inside resources folder.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the snap of appContext in it.